# How to do this SQL operation with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a sql operation:

```
    SELECT
        date,
        type,
        SUM(COALESCE(value, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY type) value
    FROM my_df
```

I know that SUM can be done with `groupby().sum()`, but I don't understand what should be for `SUM(COALESCE(value, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY type)` How to do that with Python?

Comment: You could try using the [pandasql](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql/) library.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have dataframe as `df`. `SUM(COALESCE(value, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY type)` is SQL window function that's roughly equivalent to `cumsum` in pandas:

```
df.value = df.value.fillna(0)    # == COALESCE(value, 0)
df['value'] = df.sort_values('type').groupby('date').value.cumsum()   # == SUM(COALESCE(value, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY date ORDER BY type)
df[['date', 'type', 'value']]    # == SELECT ... FROM df
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct - doesn't the COALESCE serve to only select the first none NaN values for each group?

Comment: @Grismar No `Coalesce` replace all nulls with specified value, in OP's case `0`.

Comment: From the Transact-SQL documentation: "Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL." - are there different implementations? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That's actually what it means. Assume you have `coalesce(expr1, expr2, expr3, ...)`, it takes the first non null from all expressions. So when you do `coalesce(value, 0)`, if value is not null, the result is value, if value is null, the result is 0 since it's the next non null value.

Comment: Ah, I see I misinterpreted how COALESCE would work in context of OVER, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer is not correct, as it assumes COALESCE works as a window function, which it doesn't. However, I'm leaving it here in case someone is looking for exactly that answer anyway. OP likely needs what @psidom posted.

Since the Transact-SQL selects the first non-null value for each date, when ordering the rows for that date by type (and selects 0 in case there are no non-null values), this does the same using `pandas` (which I'm assuming you're using as you refer to DataFrame):

```
from pandas import DataFrame

data = [
    # should result in 20 for this date, first that's not None once sorted
    {'date':'2021-01-01', 'type':'a', 'value': None},
    {'date':'2021-01-01', 'type':'c', 'value': 10},
    {'date':'2021-01-01', 'type':'b', 'value': 20},
    # should result in 10 for this date, only value
    {'date':'2021-01-02', 'type':'a', 'value': 10},
    # should result in 0 for this date, as there are no values that are not None
    {'date':'2021-01-03', 'type':'a', 'value': None},
]

df = DataFrame(data)
print(df.iloc[
    df.sort_values('type')
        .groupby('date')
        .apply(
            lambda x: x['value'].first_valid_index()
        ).fillna(0).astype(int)
]['value'])
```

I wrote this naively chaining the operations needed together - it may be possible to optimise it a bit.